# How do I fix the issue : npm ERR! code ENOTCACHED

Tags: node.js, npm, yocto

My BSP is  Yocto Project 3.4 (Honister).

Nodejs is v16.11.1, and npm is v8.0.0.

I refer Yocto Project Development Tasks Manual 3.22.7. Creating Node Package Manager (NPM) Packages, but when I "devtool build cute-files", I meet errors.

At first, the mime can't find some modules, so I add them from git.
But now the yocto report an error :

```
npm ERR! code ENOTCACHED

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/commander failed: cache mode is 'only-if-cached' but no cached response is available.
```

I google about ENOTCACHED, but I couldn't find any useful information.

Would you tell how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a Internet connection? If yo what happens when you curl the url? `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/commander`

Comment: The  internet connection is work well. I test "curl https://registry.npmjs.org/commander", and I got lots of info.

Comment: Try to clear the cache with `npm cache clean –force` and try to install it again.

Comment: I run "npm cache clean --force", but it still issues "npm ERR! code ENOTCACHED"

Answer (score 1):

It appears that recipes that use npm are broken with node 16. See:

https://lists.openembedded.org/g/openembedded-core/topic/npm_bblcass_dysfunctional_in/91183010?p=

There is work on the openembedded-core Kirkstone branch to fix this.

I was trying to add node 16 to Yocto Hardknott and while node 16 itself is not a problem, recipes that use npm fail with various errors.

Error: double-loading config "blah/blah/npmrc" as "global", previously loaded as "user"

which is resolved by updating poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/npm.py

And also this ENOTCACHED error, which requires changes to the npm.bbclass a new npm_registry.py and a new nodejs-oe-cache-native tool, as far as I can tell.

Kudos to the developer responsible for this work!